# Nexus3 docker different repo for different env, such as dev, prod

Tags: docker, nexus3

Sir,

May I ask a question, if I want to setup multiple separate repos for different env, such as dev, prod for different repo to avoid unstable image to be used in prod version. does that means I have to use different port for different repos?

Such as:

Dev Hosted:8083
Dev Group:8082

PRD Hosted:8183
PRD Hosted:8182

If so, if we would like to create many many, does that means we have to use many ports?

Answer (score 0):

Source workflows are usually different from company-to-company, but generally I recommend **single repo per service** and **multiple-branch** approach, so you can easily merge features to the `master` (eg: prod) branch from your `feature` branches which might be dedicated per environment.

Regarding static configuration I recommend to create a **generic, non-environment specific container images** that picks up all environment specific configuration from *environment variables* at startup and runtime.

On the port mapping, within the container you should always use the same ports (eg: build your image build with `82` and `83`), and only change those when you `expose` it to the host during the composition.

When you build your docker images, you can use `labels` to set which one is the `dev`, `prod` revision of those images, so you can target those easier, with `imagename:label`

With this you can specify multiple docker compositions per environment, by creating the following files:

**docker-compose.`dev`.yml**:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: "webapp:dev"
    ports:
     - "8082:82"
     - "8083:83"
    environment:
     - DEBUG=true
     - ENVIRONMENT_NAME=dev
```

**docker-compose.`prod`.yml**:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: "webapp:prod"
    ports:
     - "8182:82"
     - "8183:83"
    environment:
     - DEBUG=false
     - ENVIRONMENT_NAME=prod
```

With this configuration you can create your service compositions based on the same or similar images by running `docker-compose`:

```
# To start a DEV service composition
docker-compose up -f ./docker-compose.dev.yml 

# To start a DEV service composition
docker-compose up -f ./docker-compose.prod.yml
```

See more info about these:

- **docker-compose** reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/
- **github-flow** branching stratgey: https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/